# Xcode Server - Bot Integration does not create IPA file

Tags: xcode, continuous-integration, continuous-delivery

In summary of integration I see a link to ipa file

[image]

Environment: xcode7, mac os server 5.0.4

I can't find ipa file after success integration in post integration script.
Log from post build script:

```
submit Crashlytics: Crashlytics.framework/submit 1.3.5 (15)
submit Crashlytics: No file found at path /Library/Developer/XcodeServer/Integrations/Integration-54550b26ed9ba94f644c10b0691a1634/CIT.ipa
```

I try used the env var, like this -ipaPath "${XCS_OUTPUT_DIR}/${XCS_PRODUCT}" and got the next error

```
submit Crashlytics: Crashlytics.framework/submit 1.3.5 (15)
submit Crashlytics: Path must be to an .ipa file. To create an .ipa distribute an archive (ad-hoc) using Xcode.
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this

`"${XCS_OUTPUT_DIR}/ExportedProduct/Apps/${XCS_BOT_NAME}.ipa"`

It's the only thing working for me.

According to this [wwdc 2015](http://devstreaming.apple.com/videos/wwdc/2015/41097fby32x3opk/410/410_continuous_integration_and_code_coverage_in_xcode.pdf) presentation, `XCS_PRODUCT` should produce:

> Path to an .ipa or .app, if the bot produced one

But it's not working right now...

Answer (score 1):

In the latest Xcode Server 5.1 version just use

```
"${XCS_PRODUCT}"
```

Answer (score 0):

In Mac Server 5.2 + XCode 8.2, you have to use

`"${XCS_PRODUCT}"`

The path is temporary path. It will get deleted once integration complete which means finish the last post-script. So you won't be able to find anything in that path after bot completion.